# Filter angular 4 Coincidencias

Tags: angular, filtro

Quisiera saber como hacer para personalizar mas mi filter que ahora está así:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, arg: any): any {
    if (arg === '' || arg.length < 4) return value;
    const resultPosts = [];
    for (const post of value) {
      if (post.userM.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        resultPosts.push(post);
      };
    };
    return resultPosts;
  }

}
```

Por el momento lo unico que hace es encontrar coincidencias en una lista, empieza a buscar a partir de menos de 4 caracteres, pero a veces no me encuentra números en la segunda posición.
Por ejemplo yo busco:

M905902

Dentro de una lista como esta: 
    XME5271 
    XME5227 
    MB95534 
    M905902

Y solo me aparece MB95534 que empieza con M (la primer coincidencia) pero entro el numero 9 para reducirla y pues resulta que no regresa nada como sino existiera.

Dejo mi html:

```
   <div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row form-inner" >
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-8 mb-3 mr-3">
          <span class="has-float-label">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="MB00191" name="filterPost" [(ngModel)]="filterPost">
            <label>Buscar</label>
          </span>
      </div>

  </div>

    <table class="table table-hover table-borderless">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" *ngFor="let head of headElements" scope="col">{{head}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of elements | filter: filterPost">
          <th scope="row">{{item.dateUptate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</th>
          <td>{{item.userM.id}}</td>
          <td>{{item.result ? 'Positivo' : 'Negativo' }}</td>
          <td class="bbva-coronita_contract icon-link" (click)="openNote()">{{item.notas}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Agradezco si pudiera ayudarme a mejorar las coincidencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tuve un inconveniente similar y lo resolví así

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filtros'
})
export class FiltrosPipe implements PipeTransform {

   private data: any;

  transform(arreglo: any[], texto: string): any[] {
    if (texto === '') {
      return arreglo;
    }
    texto = texto.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return arreglo.filter(item => {
      this.data = item.nombre.toLowerCase().includes(texto);
      return this.data;
    });
  }
}
```

Como puedes ver es similar al tuyo

1. Hago un LowerCase para pasar todas las palabras a minusculas
2. arreglo.filter recorre mi lista
3. la funcion includes(texto) verifica que el campo con el que estoy comparando contenga esa palabra

Cuéntame si te funciono, un saludo :)

Answer (score 0):

te copie tu codigo y le hice una pequeña modificacion quizas te ayude

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, arg: string): any {

    return value.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) !== -1);

  }
}
```

Comment: Convendría explicarás lo que modificaste

Comment: Gracias, pero lo probe y me provoca errores.